# libblkid only works with root and after running as root

Tags: c, linux, blkid

This is the weirdest thing that I've ever seen (actually, it has a nice explanation).

I created a C code to list partitions and its own types:

```
char *get_luks_partition(void) {
    blkid_dev dev;
    blkid_cache cache;
    blkid_dev_iterate iter;
    const char *devname = NULL;
    char *ret = NULL;
    const char *type = NULL;

    if (blkid_get_cache(&cache, NULL))
        return NULL;
    blkid_probe_all(cache);

    iter = blkid_dev_iterate_begin(cache);

    while (!blkid_dev_next(iter, &dev)) {
        devname = blkid_dev_devname(dev);
        type = blkid_get_tag_value(cache, "TYPE", devname);

        if (type)
            printf("dev: %s type: %s\n", devname, type);

        if (type && !strcmp(type, "crypto_LUKS")) {
            ret = (char *) devname;
            break;
        }
    }

    blkid_dev_iterate_end(iter);

    return ret;
}
```

It does not show any device/partition and type when I run as a normal user.
So, I try to run as root and I finally see devices, partitions and types.
And when I return to user, I can see the same output as root if I run again.
See the sequence:

```
$ ./main 
dev: /dev/sr0 type: udf

$ sudo ./main 
dev: /dev/vda1 type: vfat
dev: /dev/vda2 type: xfs
dev: /dev/vda3 type: crypto_LUKS

$ ./main 
dev: /dev/vda1 type: vfat
dev: /dev/vda2 type: xfs
dev: /dev/vda3 type: crypto_LUKS
```

Does anyone know what is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the BLKID(8) man page:

> The  libblkid  library is used to identify block devices (disks) as to their content (e.g.  filesystem type) as well as extracting additional information such as filesystem labels/volume names, unique identifiers/serial num‐
>          bers.  A common use is to allow use of LABEL= and UUID= tags instead of hard-coding specific block device names into configuration files.

...

> Note  that  blkid reads information directly from devices and **for non-root users it returns cached unverified information.**

From the LIBBLKID(3) man page:

> The high-level part of the library keeps information about block
>   devices in a cache file and is verified to still be valid before being
>   returned to the user (if the user has read permission on the raw block
>   device, otherwise
>          not).  **The cache file also allows unprivileged users (normally anyone other than root, or those not in the "disk" group) to locate
>   devices by label/id.**  The standard location of the cache file can be
>   overridden by the envi‐
>          ronment variable BLKID_FILE.

So after you've run it as root, the information is cached. Afterwards that information is retrieved when you run again as non-root.